# Sandboxing linux within windows

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, privacy, sandbox

I'm trying to work out the best way to set up my computer so that I can run Linux as my main OS and Windows for gaming and working with Media Files.

I've looked into Virtualization and set up a virtual Windows machine within Fedora but someone recently suggested I look into Sandboxing Linux within Windows instead.

I've had a quick search around but everything I've found has been in reference to sandboxing Windows within Linux. So my questions are;

- What are the security differences
- How much would Windows be able to compromise the Linux Sandbox if at all
- Which set up would be the most simplistic to set up
- Performance differences

It's my understanding so far that the Windows host would have zero control over anything belonging to the Linux OS if sandboxed properly but I find it hard to believe Windows itself wouldn't be able to gain access to anything within the sandbox, the other way around sure but not that way.

I'm also under the impression that I'd simply passthrough the hardware the same way as with a virtual machine, is that correct and therefore the only performance difference would be in Windows hogging resources, which wouldn't make a difference in reality as the windows machine is the one that will need the performance anway?

How would Windows be prevented from reading data from within the sandbox, either active or at rest or inputs being sent to the Linux OS for example?

---

Any links that would help further my understanding here would be massively appreciated. I'm going to continue reading up on this topic anyway but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't wasting my time on something that wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest dual booting instead or running one OS inside of the other.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the security differences

Not that much IMHO. Your Windows can be pwned because it has access to the Internet, whether it's a VM or runs on the metal. Same for Linux. The real question is how much you can trust your backups.

> How much would Windows be able to compromise the Linux Sandbox if at all

I doubt there are malwares aiming VMs since these are often throw-away systems. But a ransomware can encrypt it its image file as any other file.

> Which set up would be the most simplistic to set up

It's easier to run a Linux VM under Windows, in particular for licence purposes. But you still have Windows around it when you don't need it, with the memory/CPU usage, the mandatory reboots, etc...

> Performance differences

In general not much. But if you want to play video games, you have to keep Windows as the main system, the 3D video card is hardly supported by the VM software. You may also have problems with special USB peripherals (at least with VirtualBox).

Two other things to investigate:

1. Windows Subsystem for Linux (aka WSL) which as its name doesn't indicate is really a Linux subsystem for Windows.
2. A second smaller/lighter PC to run Linux. Doesn't need to be expensive. A Raspberry Pi could do it.

Comment: *"But if you want to play video games, you have to keep Windows as the main system"* what about pci passthrough solutions and such which give very good performance?